# ReactNative - Listen to specific sound input - Vroom of Car

Tags: react-native, audio, audio-processing

What am trying to do is, count the revving("vroom" sound) of a physical car, through my app. Am coding in ReactNative. And I don't plan to create something complex, like communicating with the Car's inbuilt computer or anything to do this.

But instead, I was planning to create the app to listen to the nearby sounds. So if the nearby sound is that of a revving, then the app will simply count it.

I have done other features in my app, but listening to the sound and detect if it's a "vroom" sound is what am stuck with.

Based on my research, I can see that I have to make use of the [Fast Fourier Transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fast_Fourier_transform) algorithm. But am confused at how I can implement it in my ReactNative app. Am still searching for a package that has an implementation.

I have seen some apps that can be used to tune the sounds of Violin, Guitar, etc. What am trying to do is similar to this, but pretty simple. Once I get a basic idea, I will be able to get going. In my case, my app will be listening to the high decibel sound.

Any inputs would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is known as Acoustic Event Detection. Possibly you can use an Audio Classification approach. The best way to solve it is using supervised machine learning. For example a CNN on mel-spectrograms. Here is [an introduction](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uCGROOUO_wY&t=4s). You can do the same in JavaScript using Tensorflow.JS. The official documentation contains a [tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/tensorflowjs-audio-codelab/index.html).

One of the first steps is to collect a small dataset of examples of "vroom" sounds versus other loud non-vroom sounds.

Comment: Thank you. For this, we need to setup a server also isn't it? I mean my idea was to create a mobile app. But from what I understood, my app should send the sounds to the server to process (do the machine learning stuff there) and respond to the app. Am I correct? Or is it possible to do the same within the mobile app? Or does it use up the memory and CPU resources of mobile?

Comment: It will use CPU and RAM on the mobile, but it is plenty possible to do simple audio classification models there. And highly preferable for privacy and latency reasons, as well as architectural simplicity.

Comment: Thanks. I can see that TensorFlow has launched a version for ReactNative : https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/02/tensorflowjs-for-react-native-is-here.html What I need to do now is, research more on how to create the dataset, train it, and execute it